# How to proceed to test a function that receives a "Class" parameter using jMockIt?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I'm developing a function that uses reflection on a `Class<?>` object that is passed as parameter and returns a POJO with some fields populated, something like this:

```
public MyPojo functionDeveloper(Class<?> targetClass) { /*...*/ }
```

This function works fine and does what it needs to do, so no problems on this side.

Now, I need to create a unit test for this function, but I can't really figure out how to proceed here: We are supposed to mock as much as we can (which basically rules out creating a dummy parameter), with some random parameter from a generic class I would go like this:

```
@Tested
TestedClass testedClassInstance;

@Mocked
private MyGenericClass myGenericClass;

@Mocked
private Field[] fields;

@Test
public void testFunction() {

    new Expectations(testedClassInstance) {
        myGenericClass.getDeclaredFields();
        result = fields;
    }

    /* assertions here*/
}
```

...and my intention with the `Class<?>` parameter was the same: being able to tell "when the code says "targetClass.getDeclaredFields()", then return the mocked object "field" I declared before, but jMockIt is complaining about not being able to mock the `Class<?>` object.

So, how do I proceed here? I get that java.lang.Class is "special" and all that, and there's probably something I'm missing from how jMockIt works. Any idea?

Comment: from the code youve shown, you do not really need mocks. Mocks are for dependencies. You have not shown us any of your tested method's implementation, so I cannnot say if there are dependencies below. None of it's params, if I understand, are objects, so no mocks there. Are you under orders that you NEED to mock or something? Just call your tested method and assert that the results are as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Mocked` on a class, you holds a mocked instance automatically created by jmockit lib.
So, try `myGenericClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields()`
More details : https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#mocked

Answer (score 0):

You have a really simple case of a function. Functions are incredibly easy to test and rarely need mocks. They receive some input and return some output. What you need to do, is to test that some input produced some output.

```
@Tested
TestedClass testedClassInstance;

@Test
public void egReturnsAllFieldsOfTheProvidedClass() {
    MyPojo result = testedClassInstance.functionDeveloper(MyGenericClass.class)

    /* assertions here*/
}
```

Comment: Same thing I said above. This is our current environment. Too many tools in the toolbox, and now everyone is trying to hammer their nails with jackhammers.

Comment: The real problem with mocking tools I see is the lie that they are absolutely necessary. The "need to mock as much as we can" is absolutely horrible. The end result is usually code that actually tests nothing but mocks and tests that are falsely red or green after the first refactoring or change in a dependency.

Comment: Agreed. More like using the jackhammer on EVERYTHING. If it doesn't fix it...  must need more jackhammer!!

Comment: imo this is just a symptom of a much larger issue in software development. Trendiness. Using a stack or tool because it is what everyone else is doing, and not because it is the best option. Git rebase is another example. Sacrificing project history for a straight line. It has its places, but is overused, again, imo.